# append unique id file then scp in bash

Tags: bash

The `bash` (thank you @Charles Duffy) stores each `uniqueid` in an `array` and then passes them to `%q` to get the unique path. That seems to work what I am having trouble with is renaming each `.png` with the unique value in `%q`. I thought it was working but upon closer inspection, a `.png` file is being sent to `scp`.... but only 1 and with the wrong uniqueid. It seems like the first `.png` is being used by `scp`, but with the last uniqueid. In this example there are 2, but there may be more or less. I added a `loop` and that did not seem to work, I am at a loss. Thank you :).
I hope this help and thank you :).

```
├──/path/to/   ---- common path after ssh ---
│   ├── ID1*   --- unique %q represents the unique id and * represents random text after it ---
│   │   └── /%q*/folder
│   ├── ID2*   --- unique %q represents the unique id and * represents random text after it ---
│   │   └── /%q/folder
```

**Description:**

After `ssh` to the common path on the server, each unique ID from `%q` is used to further navigate to folder. In each folder there is a png (cn_results), that the unique ID from `%q` is append to (ID-cn_results) and this append file is `scp` to xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/path/to/%q*/destination.

**declare -p array**='([0]="ID1" [1]="ID2")'  --- this is where the rename value are ---

**current output in each /path/to/%q*/folder**   --- on the server---

```
cn_results.png
```

**desired output in each** /path/to/%q*/destination after `scp`

```
uniqueid1-cn_results.png
uniqueid2-cn_results.png
```

I can manually `ssh` into directory and the `.png` is there, though it is only `cn_results` before the `scp` where it is renamed/ append with the array value and then `scp`. I tried to add the loop to `scp` and rename as such:

```
printf -v cmd_q '(cd /path/to/%q*/*/folder && for ID in "${array[@]}" ; do exec sshpass -f file.txt scp "$ID" xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:path/to/destination/${ID}-cn_results.png)\n' "${array[@]}" ; done
sshpass -f out.txt ssh -o strictHostKeyChecking=no -t xxx@xxx.xx.xx.xx "$cmd_q"
```

Comment: it is, but I tried to incorporate the comments in an attempt to solve it. Thank you :).

Comment: So what are you trying to do? What should be the input be, what should be the output? Please, don't explain _how_ to do it, explain _what_ do you want to do. I imagine you have a bunch of files and a list of numbers. You want to join each number with each file creating pairs and rename each file with paired number? It would be helpful if you would list an example directory and file structure before the operation, then include the list of files then show the directory and file structure after the operation. And the files are on a remote machine accessible via ssh. Or they are not. I don't know.

Comment: honestly it is hard to understand what you want to achieve. It seems that you want to identify some unique ids or file names and then send the over scp. I would say that the sending part is not relevant to your problem but rather identifying the files. You don't give the source of the whole script, nor the directory structure. Try to make a small script to create the structure, compose the array from the file tree and echo the scp attemted command

Comment: I added details to the post that I hope will help. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command that I think might produce the desired results. It copies all files in the source-folder with the name cn_results.png to the target folder, appending a unique id to the start using `$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)`

```
find ./source-folder -name 'cn_results.png' -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "./target-folder/$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid)_memo_content.xml"' _ {} \;
```